# CreateProcess waits when exe file is invalid

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

I want to make a simple C++ program, which runs multiple exe files at once using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If an exe file is invalid (filled with random data), a message box appears and says that the file is not compatible with 64-bit Windows, which is fine, but my program waits until the message box is closed. Is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the error handling policy for your process, by calling [`SetErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621.aspx). You should do this at the very beginning of your program, during startup.

```
SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(0) | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS  
  | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

I believe that `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` is the flag relevant to your current problem but you should include the others too.

Note that there is, at least in older versions of Windows, no function to simply get the current error mode. The [`GetErrorMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679355.aspx) function was added in Vista. So instead we call `SetErrorMode(0)` which returns the previous error mode. This somewhat inconvenient API design is discussed in Raymond Chen's article here: [Disabling the program crash dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/27/198410.aspx). Of course, if you don't support XP any longer, that you can use:

```
SetErrorMode(GetErrorMode() | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX | SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS  
  | SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But can't we just call GetErrorMode to get oldMode?

Comment: You can if you target Vista and later.

Comment: On Windows 7, the security warning from opening downloaded executables also pauses the program. Is there also a way around this (i am using ShellExecute now, if this is different)?

Comment: You can delete the alternate file stream that indicates that the file was downloaded from an external source.

Comment: Do note that Win7+ also has `SetThreadErrorMode()`. Yes, you *should* call `SetErrorMode()` at startup to disable error dialogs process-wide. But let's face it, how many people *actually* do that? How many people even realize that `Set(Thread)ErrorMode()` even exist? You could alternatively use `SetThreadErrorMode()` to configure just the thread that is calling `CreateProcess()` (if different than the main thread) as a workaround without changing the behavior of the entire app.

Comment: @Remy I call SetErrorMode. It's quite easy to do so. Are you suggesting that we should not do so? Changing the behaviour of the app is exactly what is desired.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I said we should. Good for you if you do, but not everyone else does.